# How to make ios extension depend on the app that embeds it

Tags: ios, xcode8, ios-extensions

A typical situaion:
I have an app Foo which embeds a share extension Bar,
Bar shows up in Target Dependencies for Foo.

Naturally I can not add app Foo to the list of Target Dependencies for extension Bar cause that would create a circular dependence.

Both targets depend on framework that contains shared code (lets call that Baz).

So while debugging an extension I'm tired of running an installing
the app first.

Is there any way to have the app with updated code installed automatically when I run the extension?

If I bypass a switch to target Foo build, install then the changes
I just made to Baz do not show up when I run Foo (well, Bar was not rebuild and reinstalled so why they should have showed up?)

Would appreciate any leads to make this experience any less tedious.
This is on xcode 8.2.1 in case it matters